# SQL: How do I find which movie genre a user watched the most? (IMDb personal project)

Tags: sql, ms-access, imdb

I'm currently working on a personal project and I could use a little help. Here's the scenario:

I'm creating a database (MS Access) for all of the movies myself and some friends have ever watched. We rated all of our movies on IMDb and used the export feature to get all of the movie data and our movie ratings. I plan on doing some summary analysis on Excel. One thing I am interested in is the most common movie genre that each person watched. Below is my current scenario. Note that the column "const" is the movies' unique IDs. I also have individual tables for each person's ratings and the following tables are the summary tables that make up the combination of all the movies we have watched.

Here's the table I had: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnxOy.jpg

I assigned each genre an ID, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgPku.jpg

And here is a table where I have separate instances for each movie ID and a unique genre: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H8QR.jpg

I want to find a way to count up all of the genres that each person watches. Any advice? I would love to provide any additional information that you need!

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, here is an example of one user's data: http://imgur.com/JMcfSiw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have at least one table which has one row per `user` and `const` (movie watched). In the 3 example tables you posted nothing shows who watched which movies, which is information you need to solve your problem. You mention having "individual tables for each person's ratings," so I assume you have that information. You will want to combine all of them though, into a table called `PERSON_MOVIE` or something of the like.

So let's say your second table is called `GENRE` and its columns are ID, Genre.

Let's say your third table is called `GENRE_MOVIE` and its columns are Const and ID (ID corresponds to ID on the GENRE table)

Let's say the fourth table, which you did not post, but which is required, is called `PERSON_MOVIE` and its columns are person, Const, rating.

You could then write a query like this:

```
select vw1.*, ge.genre
  from (select um.person, gm.id as genre_id, count(*) as num_of_genre
          from user_movie um
         inner join genre_movie gm
            on um.const = gm.const
         group by um.person, gm.id) vw1
 inner join (select person, max(num_of_genre) as high_count
               from (select um.person, gm.id, count(*) as num_of_genre
                       from user_movie um
                      inner join genre_movie gm
                         on um.const = gm.const
                      group by um.person, gm.id) x
              group by person) vw2
    on vw1.person = vw2.person
   and vw1.num_of_genre = vw2.high_count
 inner join genre ge
    on vw1.genre_id = ge.id
```

Edit re: your comment:

So right now you have multiple tables reflecting people's ratings of movies. You need to combine those into a table called `PERSON_MOVIE` or something similar (as in example above).

There will be 3 columns on the table: person, const, rating

I'm not sure if access supports the traditional `create table as select` query but ordinarily you would be able to construct such a table in the following way:

```
create table person_movie as
select 'Bob', const, [You rated]
from ratings_by_bob
union all
select 'Sally', const, [You rated]
from ratings_by_sally
union all
select 'Jack', const, [You rated]
from ratings_by_jack
....
```

If not, just combine the tables manually and add a third column as shown indicating what users are reflected by each row. Then you can run my initial query.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Here is an image of what I currently have for each user. This is a snippet of Alex's data: http://imgur.com/JMcfSiw

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple tables with one person's ratings per table. You should have one table with that information, with the person reflected as a column. So in your image you need a table with a third column and on those rows you would see 'Alex'. Then on other rows you would see Jack, Jill, etc. all on one table. In the example query I posted I assume this new table you will be creating is called `PERSON_MOVIE` and I assume its columns will be `person`, `const`, and `rating`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. This definitely makes sense and I will start working on these changes!